# Regex to match 'product' but not 'production' or 'products'?

Tags: regex

Is there any way I can write a regular expression that matches 'product' but not 'production' or 'products'?

The input string could be 'oil production', or just 'production', or 'products'.

Comment: looks like you want /\b \b/    as in /\bproduct\b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for a "negative lookahead": `product(?!s|ion)` will match product, but if it's immediately followed by `s` or `ion` it will ignore it and keep looking.